# How to re-render a component of the page with PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'am starting with PHP and Laravel.

I'am mostly used to Vue.js and React on frontend and I'am now trying this blade template from Laravel.

I just wanted to make an API call and re-render a small component of the page with the API response but it seems I'am having some hard time trying to do it.

This is the template part that I'am trying to re-render:

```html
<div class="section-block">
    <h2 class="section-title"> Ask a question </h2>
    <form id="assistant-form" method="post" action="/decisions/assistant">
        @csrf
        <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
            <input type="text" name="userInput" class="form-control mx-2" placeholder="Your question...">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info">Ask</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="assistant-content">
    @include('decision.ai_assistant')
</div>
```

I make an API call once the form is submitted and I should re-render the div with id="assistant-content" but somehow when I submit the form the entire page just re-render to a blank page with the POST route as URL.

```php
Route::post('/decisions/assistant', function (Request $request)
{
    Log::info("Request data: " . json_encode($request->all()));
    $userInput = $request->input('userInput');
    Log::info("Received user input: " . $userInput);
    $ai_response = app(ApiController::class)->makeOpenAICall($userInput);
    Log::info("API response: " . $ai_response);
});
```

I know that the API call worked and I got the response (I checked it in the backend). I'am just intrigued on this behaviour from blade/html...

Can't I just re-render a small part of the page? If so, how should I do it ? Using pure javascript ?

I tried using some pure javascript but it simply seems to be ignored :

```js
@section('js')
<script src='{{asset('js/flatpickr.min.js')}}'></script>
<script src='{{asset('js/bootstrap-select.min.js')}}'></script>
<script>
    document.getElementById('assistant-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

        // Serialize form data
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        // Send an AJAX request
        fetch('/decisions/assistant', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // Update the content of the 'assistant-content' div
            document.getElementById('assistant-content').innerHTML = data.messageContent;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: **Route::post('/decisions/assistant'....** must return the view *decision.ai_assistant* that you want to update with JS

Comment: you're right! But do you confirm that the only way to re-render only a single "element" of the page would be with JS. Correct ? Laravel doesn't have that type of functionality

Comment: @Simao JavaScript Ajax is indeed the best option to do that in Laravel, the fact that it makes async calls let you do whatever you want with that.

Comment: @Simao Basically yes. Anyway you can consider AlpineJS instead of bare JS or Livewire

Comment: Yeah, Livewire's the way to go if you want AJAX-style but in PHP exclusively.